# Are there analogues of globalStorage in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to access data, which has been put in some local storage by a website page, using a Chrome extension.
Are there javascript libraries which can help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var i, l = localStorage.length;

for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    console.log(key+" = "+value);
}
```